# Blank page of death with pagination and blog article link

Tags: ee2

Getting the blank page of death with pagination links and full article links.

Here's the page I'm working on:

Here's the code I'm using:

```
{embed="inc/.header.doc-open"}
{embed="inc/.header.nav-blog"}
<div class="blog-section clearfix general tan-bg">

    <div class="clearfix">

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_entry|blog_link|blog_photo|blog_quote|blog_video" limit="2" paginate="bottom" orderby="date"}
    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
  {if channel_short_name == 'blog_link'}
</div><!-- end .wrapper -->

  <div class="link blog-entry">

      <h2><a href="{blog_link_url}">{title}</a></h2>

      <p>{blog_link_description}</p>

      <span class="date">Posted on <strong>{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">Permalink</a></span>

  </div><!-- end .link -->

  {if:elseif channel_short_name == 'blog_quote'}
  <div class="quote blog-entry">

      <h2><a href="{blog_quote_url}">{title}</a></h2>

      <blockquote>{blog_quote}</blockquote>

      <span class="source"><a href="{blog_quote_url}">{blog_quote_source}</a></span>
      <p>{blog_quote_description}</p>
      <span class="date">Posted on <strong>{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">Permalink</a></span>

  </div><!-- end .quote -->
  {if:elseif channel_short_name == 'blog_entry'}
  <div class="entry blog-entry">

      <h2><a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">{title}</a></h2>

      <span class="author">Written by <strong>{author}</strong></span>

      <p>{blog_entry_summary} <span><a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">Read&nbsp;More&hellip;</a></span></p>

      <span class="date">Posted on <strong>{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">Permalink</a></span>

  </div><!-- end .entry -->
  {if:elseif channel_short_name == 'blog_photo'}
  <div class="photo blog-entry">

      <h2><a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">{title}</a></h2>

      <img src="{blog_photo_upload}" alt="" />
      <p>{blog_photo_description}</p>
      <span class="date">Posted on <strong>{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">Permalink</a></span>

  </div><!-- end .photo -->
  {if:elseif channel_short_name == 'blog_video'}
  <div class="video blog-entry">

      <h2><a href="{blog_video_url}">{title}</a></h2>

      <div class="video-container blog-entry">
          <!-- start of embed code -->
          {blog_video_embed}
          <!-- end of embed code -->
      </div>
      <p>{blog_video_description}</p>
      <span class="date">Posted on <strong>{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{title_permalink="blog"}">Permalink</a></span>

  </div><!-- end .video -->
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries} 
</div>

</div><!-- end .content-section -->

{embed="inc/.footer.doc-close"}
```

Any thoughts? I'm sure I'm making a very basic mistake... I've never attacked this type of functionality with an EECMS site.

Comment: Whilst nothing looks out of place, try and remove all if statements and test individual code. Once you've identified where the issue is you can reintroduce your if statements.

Comment: I did sir, to no avail. Anything else I could do? I saw in another post where a guy removed the "relationship" tags...? I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Hmmm. Problem solving 101. Does any page render properly ? A white screen can be investigated by turning on display errors in the control panel. Consult the ee documents to find where to find. Probably a memory issue. Happy new year, will check back in 2014 :)

Comment: I'm wondering - why are you setting the paginate loop at the top of the render when it's set for paginate="bottom"? Wouldn't you put that just before closing the entries loop?

Comment: @stuartmcd69 The permalink (to the main article) doesn't work either, it somehow is redirecting to the homepage. I tried doing the $debug tag at the top of the page with no luck... Do you have to have that tag AND turn on 'display errors' in the control panel?

Thanks for the help, bud. Happy New Year!

Comment: @Holland Good question... I have no basis for putting the paginate loop at the top, it's just how I saw it being used in one example. I'm still not terribly familiar with paginate, obviously, or I wouldn't be having these issues!

I don't know if I'm supposed to put the paginate loop at the bottom, but will give it a try. 

Thanks!

Comment: I always stuck it at the bottom of where I wanted pagination to be applied. If it's at the top, perhaps it's paginating before displaying (I'm away on the phone so I can't check this) but let us know if it made a difference

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice. It didn't make any difference placing the pagination at the bottom. I think the parameter that places it at the bottom seems pretty solid.

**Problem solved:** I contacted Andy Johnson (shapingthepage.com) because I was following his tutorial. He suggested I use hard coded segment logic in the main index template, which I did and it worked. Not very elegant, but everything I do in EE seems to be a hack of some sort...

Thanks guys!